# Is "if one day I had something to say I would write a book" correct?

Tags: verbs, conditional-constructions

is the sentence correct to express something that could happen or not in the future:

*"If one day I had something to say I would write a book"*

Thank you all.

Comment: It's more common to use *if one day I **have** something to say, I **will** write a book*, but both *had* and *would* work too, in various combinations. What is the specific area of concern?

Comment: It's perfectly correct, Pete.

Comment: Thank you all. Sorry If I missed some context information, it is about a declaration I made in the past, like: I told him that If one day I ...... (had/ would have?) something to say [about that topic] I ..... (would/will?) write a book. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The correctness of this sentence depends entirely on the intention and context. To say,

> *If one day I had something to say I would write a book.*

is fine if you are talking about your past, and more specifically, a habitual action in the past. To illustrate:

"If one day [during a relevant period of time in my past] I had something to say I would [habitually] write a book [to express whatever it was I had to say]."

Most likely, however, you would not be writing an entire book every time you had something to say (unless you were at some point in your life Stephen King). More probably, you would **work on** a book/literary project until you ran out of ideas, then abandon it for a while and resume writing the next time you had something to say.

For these reasons, I assume you intend to convey something more like this:

"If one day I **have** something to say I **will**/**may** write a book."

Here, you are either *declaring* that, in the uncertain event that one day (in the future) you have something to say, you will (at that point in time) write a book, or you are stating that you are *considering* writing a book (at some non-specific point in your future), but your decision will heavily depend on whether or not you ever have something to say.

I hope that wasn't too confusing, and I hope this answer helped you!

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. So if I am in the present I can declare that "If one day I have something to say I will write a book". But if I am speaking about a declaration I made in the past? Like for example: I told him that If one day I ...... (had/would have?) something to say [about that topic] I .....  (would/will?) write a book. Thank you again.

Comment: You could say, "I told him that if one day I had something to say I would write a book." if the declaration is in the past and the event of you writing a book has either occurred or is occurring in the present. If the declaration is in the past and the event may or may not happen in the future, use, "I told him that if one day I have an idea I will/may write a book."